# Should Access-Control-Allow-Origin be set only to localhost:4200 for full stack web app?

Tags: web-applications, server

I am developing a web application where requests to the backend server will be made from the front end client application - angular running on port 4200. Is there any reason to allow more origins other than http://localhost:4200 if you server is intended only for authenticated users on your website? Thanks.

Comment: No, however `http://localhost:4200` will work only on your machine, later on it will be something like `https://www.example.com` I guess. So you should make this value configurable so that you can set the correct origin for development and production environments. (Much like you will have to make the URL of your backend, that the frontend uses, configurable as well, since it may be `http://localhost:8888` now but `https://api.example.com` later.)

Comment: @CherryDT Great, thanks.